# strange output of getline(cin,str)

Tags: c++, string, getline

In the code given below i was trying to take string input from cin but it showed some runtime error.

```
int main(){

int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    string s,pat;
    cin>>s>>pat;
    int q;
    cin>>q;
     vector<pair<int,char> > queries;
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cin>>queries[i].first;
        cin>>queries[i].second;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    cout<<pat<<endl;
}
return 0;}
```

So i used getline instead of just cin like:

```
getline(cin,s);
getline(cin,pat);
```

and it showed output like

```
abcde
```

for the input

```
2 abcde bc 3 0 p 1 q 2 w wxyz cde 2 0 t 1 z
```

so what appears to me is that getline is taking space after t which is stored in string s for the first test case and the first string i.e "abcde" is stored in string pat and i don't get why it prints empty line for 2nd test case.

So to get rid of that extra space after t, i added a extra string to store that space just like:

```
int main(){
int t;
cin>>t;
string z;
getline(cin,z);
while(t--){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    string pat;
    getline(cin,pat);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    cout<<pat<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

and it worked for input

```
2 abcde bc wxyz cde
```

but when i add this code

```
string s,pat;
    getline(cin,s);
    getline(cin,pat);
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    vector<pair<int,char> > queries;
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cin>>queries[i].first;
        cin>>queries[i].second;
    }
```

it shows runtime error. Please help..

Comment: Saying `queries[i]=something` does not put anything into a vector, it only modifies an existing value in the vector. Since you declared an empty vector and did absolutely nothing, whatsoever, to initialize it with anything, `cin>>queries[i].first` attempts to initialize a non-existent value in the vector. Hello corrupted memory. Hello crash. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use vectors, and read the part that explains how to put new values into a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix the problem you are seeing.  As was mentioned in a comment above, you have an empty vector and are trying to access an element of the vector.  You need to create the pair and then push it into the vector:

```
for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
    int v;
    char c;
    cin>> v >> c;
    queries.push_back(make_pair(v, c));
}
```

To add further explanation to what the actual problem is, you can think of your vector as a closet in which you can put a series of boxes.  Each box is assigned a number (index) when it is placed in the closet.  Until you place a box in the closet, the closet is empty.  It has the potential to store boxes, but there are no boxes there.  When you wrote the line `queries[i]`, you were essentially walking to the closet and searching for a box with a particular index, and then trying to put something in it.  In your case though, all you had was an empty closet so when you tried to put something in a box (for instance box number 0), there was no box found and you received this run time error.  In order to ask for a box with a specific index, it has to exist and be in the closet.  The code change I made was to actually create the box and then put it into the closet.

Comment: Thanks. Just realised that i forgot to give the size of vector.